# Kendo Grid Save Changes

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, savechanges

I have a kendo Grid that I make changes to and this saves to database.

There is a button on the form that I submit additional information to a different database. I would like to check that the kendo grid has all changes saved when I click this button.

If there are still some outstanding changes(red arrow in kendo grid) the user will have to save changes before proceeding.

Can this be achieved with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I was able to determine if there were unsaved changes by reading the `dirty` flag from the datasource. I'm not sure if this is documented with Kendo at all, I just found it by chance poking around the datasource. Hopefully it will help you out.

For "myGrid":

```
var boolDirty = false;

$.each($("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._data, function () {
    if (this.dirty) { boolDirty = true; }
});
```