# Kendo Grid Select All and Save

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm working on a functionality on a Kendo Grid. There is a table and every row has a checkbox, there is a `Select All` option that checks all of the checkboxes and there is a button next to that `Select All` option to `Update All` rows, when you click on `Update All` it will update the `Status` of the selected rows within the Grid, but it hasn't updated yet on the database. To update those rows on the database you have to click a `Save Changes` button. The problem I'm having is that the performance is very very slow for more than a 100 rows when I click `Update All` button, and I know why, in the `Javascript` this is the code that makes the step very slow:

```
  var items = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data();
$.each(selectedRows, function (index, r) {
 var indexOf = rows.indexOf(r);
 var item = items[indexOf];
item.set('STATUS', status); //This line of code is very slow for more than 100 records
});
```

So using the set method makes this process really slow, when there are more than 300 records Chrome becomes unresponsive. So I have changed it to this:

```
  var items = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data();
$.each(selectedRows, function (index, r) {
 var indexOf = rows.indexOf(r);
 var item = items[indexOf];
item.STATUS = status; //It works fast now
});
kendoGrid.refresh();
```

The grid is updating correctly on the frontend, but when I click `Save Changes` the controller that should save those records on the database is not called, this is because the changes on the `Status` column are not being detected when I use the last syntax..
What is the difference between

```
item.set('STATUS', status);
```

and

```
item.STATUS = status; 
kendoGrid.refresh();
```

Why on the second step the rows are being saved to the database using the `set()` method but when I use `item.STATUS = status;` and click on `Save Changes` the rows that have changes are not being send on the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20959758/5614045
And updated my syntax like this:

```
 var items = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data();
$.each(selectedRows, function (index, r) {
 var indexOf = rows.indexOf(r);
 var item = items[indexOf];
item.STATUS = status; //It works fast now
item.dirty = true; //Added this line of code.
});
kendoGrid.refresh();
```

And it works now, apparently there is a `dirty` flag that when is set to true it means the item have changed...